# Read tables from HTML page by changing the ID using python

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, datatable

I am using the html link below to read the table in the page:
http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=2016664

The last part of the link`(allbin)` is an ID. This ID changes and by using different IDs you can access different tables and records. The link although remains the same, just the ID in the end changes every time. I have like 1000 more different IDs like this. So, How can I actually use those different IDs to access different tables and join them together?

Output Like this,

```
ID         Number         Type             FileDate
2016664   NB 14581-26     New Building    12/21/2020
4257909   NB 1481-29      New Building    3/6/2021
4138920   NB 481-29       New Building    9/4/2020
```

List of other ID for use:

```
['4257909', '4138920', '4533715']
```

This was my attempt, I can read a single table with this code.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=2016664'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html,header=0)
df = df_list[3]
    
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all pages from list of IDs you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

url = "http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin={}&allcount={}"


def get_info(ID, page=1):
    out = []
    while True:
        try:
            print("ID: {} Page: {}".format(ID, page))
            t = requests.get(url.format(ID, page), timeout=1).text
            df = pd.read_html(StringIO(t))[3].loc[1:, :]
            if len(df) == 0:
                break
            df.columns = ["NUMBER", "NUMBER", "TYPE", "FILE DATE"]
            df["ID"] = ID
            out.append(df)
            page += 25
        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
            print("Timeout...")
            continue
    return out


list_of_ids = [2016664, 4257909, 4138920, 4533715]

dfs = []
for ID in list_of_ids:
    dfs.extend(get_info(ID))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=None)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                              NUMBER                                                                            NUMBER                                                                              TYPE                                                                         FILE DATE       ID
1                                                                      ALT 1469-1890                                                                               NaN                                                                        ALTERATION                                                                        00/00/0000  2016664
2                                                                      ALT 1313-1874                                                                               NaN                                                                        ALTERATION                                                                        00/00/0000  2016664
3                                                                        BN 332-1938                                                                               NaN                                                                   BUILDING NOTICE                                                                        00/00/0000  2016664
4                                                                        BN 636-1916                                                                               NaN                                                                   BUILDING NOTICE                                                                        00/00/0000  2016664
5                                                                    CO NB 1295-1923                                                                             (PDF)                                                          CERTIFICATE OF OCCUPANCY                                                                        00/00/0000  2016664

...
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Looks good. What If I want the Type ="NEW BUILDING" only. Where I should put it in?

Comment: @TahsinAlam You can perform filtering on final dataframe. For example `print(df[df['TYPE'].eq("NEW BUILDING")])`

Comment: Yes right but since there are lot of ids so I don't want to read everything from the page. Is there a way I can also include it in the loop so I only read IDs with type 'NEW BUILDING' only? Thanks.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thanks for you help again. Appreciate it.

Comment: how can I actually do it if a have like 1000 ids from another dataframe to handle? I tried 'df["ID].tolist()' which works and convert those IDs to list but takes a lot of time to process and return timeout. Any other way to work many IDs? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will extract all the tables in a web page

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

url = 'http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/ActionsByLocationServlet?requestid=1&allbin=2016664'

df_list = pd.read_html(url) #returns as list of dataframes from the web page

print(len(df_list)) #print the number of dataframes

i = 0

while i < len(df_list): #loop through the list to print all tables

```
df = df_list[i]

print(df)

i = i + 1
```