# Read tables from HTML page with a list of many IDs using python

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, datatables

[Read tables from HTML page by changing the ID using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68579423/read-tables-from-html-page-by-changing-the-id-using-python)

It is the same question as this one but instead of list of few IDs I have to through 10k different IDs. How do I actually manage to read the web page with that many IDs in my list?

Thanks.

Comment: I found that is your own question. I personally didn't understood the question. Are you trying to say `['4257909', '4138920', '4533715']` you this more then 10k like in that question you have 1k?

Comment: Yes, instead of few listed IDs if I work with many more IDs how should I approach?I have 10K IDs in my list.

Comment: You don't need data in any right order, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiprocessing` to scrape multiple link simultaneously(parallelly):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
    
def scrape(url):
    #Scraper script

p = Pool(10)
# This “10” means that 10 URLs will be processed at the same time.
p.map(scrape, list_of_all_urls)
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

Here we map function scrape with list_of_all_urls and Pool p will take care of executing each of them concurrently. This is similar to looping over `list_of_all_urls` but here it is done concurrently. If number of URLs is 100 and we specify Pool(20), then it will take 5 iterations (100/20) and 20 URLs will be processed in single time.

This result may not be in order because all 10/20... urls are running simultaneously.